# Trigger patterns

Tags: pattern

There is a pattern outlined for writing the triggers in Salesforce here :

http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/trigger-pattern-for-tidy-streamlined-bulkified-triggers.

How Apex Trigger Pattern (Tony Scott) can be enhanced to make a future call/Batch Job from the trigger? Or can we use it as it is and call the batch/future from handler.Finally();?

Also what are the major advantages we have of using this patter as compared to simply calling the class methods from the trigger apart from readability/maintainence/bulkification/controlling the order of execution?

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: you might also want to look at the patterns in Andrew Fawcett's excellent book Force.com Enterprise Architecture - http://www.amazon.com/Force-com-Enterprise-Architecture-Andrew-Fawcett/dp/1782172998 for an expanded look a best practice design patterns over and above trigger patterns

Comment: Many Thanks Keith. I havent got hold of the book yet, but still if you could please answer the curious questions i have regarding the patterns above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked:

> How Apex Trigger Pattern (Tony Scott) can be enhanced to make a future call/Batch Job from the trigger?

Answer:

1. Declare a collection variable for the triggerHandler class that keeps track of all IDs you wish to send to the future method
2. In the `afterInsert(..)` and `afterUpdate(..)` methods, determine if the sobject in question should have its (or some related) ID added into the collection from #1
3. In the `andFinally()` - do the future call passing the ids in the collection from #1

You asked:

> Also what are the major advantages we have of using this pattern as compared to simply calling the class methods from the trigger apart from readability/maintainence/bulkification/controlling the order of execution?

The most important thing about this pattern is only one trigger per sobject. All order dependency is enforced within the logic of the `beforeXXX(...)` and `afterXXX(...)` methods.

The `bulkBefore()` and `bulkAfter()` methods provide a way to do all the marshaling of related sobjects in a SOQL-minimizing way so the various beforeXXX and after XXX handlers don;t have to do any SOQL (nor should they).  `andFinally()` provides the single place to do related object DML or launch of async operations.

From personal experience, if using a pattern, use it consistently as it makes debugging easier, makes looking back at code written years go easier, and it provides a place to introduce enhancements only once (such as logging limits or trigger recursion control).  It also provides a way to enforce discipline across many developers on the same project who may otherwise generate multiple styles of code that is harder to maintain.

Others would argue that the pattern is overkill for dead simple triggers on minor sobjects.

The Force.com Enterprise Architecture goes beyond the Tony Scott pattern by focusng on separation of concerns, where triggers are represented by a domain layer that in turn works with selectors, services, units of work, and so on.  If you have a rich set of customizations using code that affect many sobjects, or, you have common services invoked from many places (REST, client-side javascript, batch, ...), Force.com Enterprise Architecture is well-worth looking into.